# How can I create a bouncing logo screensaver?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver, group-policy

I'm looking to create a basic screensaver, background set to a specific color, with a specific image (or images) bouncing around on the computer screen.

For reference, the majority of the computers are running Windows 7, 64-bit, we also have a few Windows 8 computers, and would hope it to be Win8 compatible, if we were to upgrade.

Also, I'm looking to deploy this screensaver to a corporation using Microsoft Group Policy. I'm already familiar with the policies I need to set to accomplish this. From my understanding of it, the GPO option available to me is to pick a specific .scr file, and it will enforce that as the computer's screensaver.

I know Microsoft has a built in Photo/Slideshow screensaver, but i cannot find a way to "push" a configuration for that screensaver to multiple computers. I can set it as the screensaver, but not with the specific image I want. I also do not see an option to set the background color used.

I've searched for other tools without success.

Comment: Not an answer so I'll leave as a comment. WHY! You are wasting power and money by making the computers do work that they don't need to. Set all the computers to blank the screen after the set time, any reasonable monitor will go into power saving mode saving your organisation money and saving the planet!

Comment: I agree with Julian, move on to a bigger problem in your enterprise, set a GPO to turn off the monitors after 15min and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own ;)
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html

I ran through this tutorial last year an made a nice one for our company using a logo and a background flash. Not too difficult if your proficient at image editing and have a basic level of coding knowledge. I ended up writing my own because the commercially available screensaver tools I found were abysmal.

We run the screensaver for 15 minutes, at which point the monitors go to sleep.